# @Transactional avoids exception in repository methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am using `@Transactional` for service method

Suppose we have such methods

```
@Transactional 
public void doWork() {
    User user = new User(1);
    user = userRepository.save(user);

    doOtherWorkIfAllIsOk(user);
}

private void doOtherWorkIfAllIsOk(User user) {
    System.out.println("Everything is alright");
    user.setName("Bob")
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

If, for example, I did not fill in some required field for the User, which has `nullable = false`, the transaction will catch an exception that will throw the repository method and my method will continue execution by calling the method `doOtherWorkIfAllIsOk()`.

How to configure transaction behavior so that Spring does not catch exceptions when calling a repository method. I need that if an error occurs in the repository method, then the doWork() method throws this exception and is interrupted and the doOtherWorkIfAllIsOk(User user) method should not be called, because now if there is an error in the repository method, the doOtherWorkIfAllIsOk(User user) method is called.

Comment: The `@Column` annotation is only used for generating the tables. It is not used for validation

Comment: BTW: You should do the validation not on the database layer. Do it in the businesslogic

Comment: i think the repository.save() should throw exception immediately now if it fails to insert the user to the DB . what do you want to do actually ?

Comment: epository.save() throws exception immediately, but @Transactional catches this exception and returns to continue execution of my method but it shouldn't continue execution.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider a different approach. Getting the database or persistence framework to auto-throw errors that you then catch to control the flow of you code can be improved upon. There are many ways you can do this but I would consider something like the following:

```
@Transactional 
public void doWork() {
    User user = new User(1);
    if (isUserValid(user)) {
       user = userRepository.save(user);
       doOtherWork(user);
    } else {
     //log.warn("user is invalid");
    }

   
}

private boolean isUserValid(User user) {
   //check user, return false if not valid
   // perhaps logging at debug level what's wrong is also helpful
}
```

There are a couple of points to this:

- You explicitly declare what makes a user invalid which can be tested independent of a database or database framework. Additionally, the way your code is now, someone else or you in the future, would not intuitively know what makes a user valid.
- Using exceptions for flow control is usually a bad idea and an anti-pattern. Exceptions should be exceptional, not part of your normal business logic
- Since you mentioned `nullable = false`, you may want to look at the Hibernate Validation project to use annotation based validation. If you are dealing with a Spring Web project, you can enable this easily. However, one thing I would also suggest is that you do not expose your database class / entity `User` at the web or presentation layer that is accepting the form fields. It is better to work with, so called, data transfer objects that handle the validation for you. Once that is valid, you can create database objects from that to save to your DB.

Example:

```
public class NewUserForm {

  @NotNull
  private String username;

}

//validation happens by the caller of this service layer method or before transforming here
public saveUser(NewUserForm userForm) {
    User user = transformToUser(userForm);
    userRepository.save(user);
    
}
```

For more info on getting started with validation in Spring, you can Google `Spring Hibernate Validation` and you will find plenty of "getting started" guides on this.